# p4 submit without submitting out-of-date files

Tags: perforce

I want to use p4 submit command to submit a specific changelist, but unlike the GUI submit form, with command line you can submit even out-of-date files.

For example, the latest file revision is #10.
I sync revision #5, modify the file and then I'm able to submit with p4 submit command.
Is there a way to avoid it? In other words, is there a way to achieve the same behavior as with GUI?

Comment: This is not correct.  The submit will fail if any files are out of date.  (This behavior is enforced by the server, not by the GUI.)  If you believe you have found a situation where this is not the case, please reproduce it from the command line and paste a transcript into your question.

Comment: @Samwise After you try to submit you might be asked to resolve out-of-date files. After you resolve them they are still marked as #5/10. At this point, you are able to submit such files with p4 submit, but the GUI won't let you do that saying that you must get the latest revision first.

Comment: Resolving after a failed submit is exactly the same as doing a "get latest" followed by resolving with respect to the contents of the file that you're submitting -- the file is no longer out of date at that point, since the resolve brings the file content up to date.  The only difference (and the reason you see #5/10 in the UI or in `p4 have`) is that a revert will bring you back to #5 if you haven't done an *explicit* sync.

Comment: @Samwise Now it makes sense to me. Thank you for the great explanation!